# Strange format of java.util.Date in toString method

Tags: java, date

In documentation is written that `date.toString` return date in format:

```
dec mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

so I println date of birth of my person:

```
logger.error(person.getDateOfBirth().toString() + "dddddddddddddddd");
```

but it look different:

```
- 1955-04-14 00:00:00.0dddddddddddddddd
```

Why ?

UPDATED:

I set date like this:

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(1955, 3, 14);
            calendar.getTime()
```

I am expecting date in format which is written in documentation

Comment: what are you expecting ???

Comment: What does getDateOfBirth() returns ?

Comment: what value do you set for the person date of birth?

Comment: getDateOfBirth() return same value

Comment: What locale have you set?

Comment: I dont set any locale but now I am in czech republic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure, the type of

```
person.getDateOfBirth()
```

is **java.util.Date**.

By looking at the output, I guess its **java.sql.Timestamp**

Answer (score 0):

What I get http://ideone.com/aspxEF is as expected

```
Thu Apr 14 09:04:33 GMT 1955
```

If you use the code as you suggest you should see the current time in there somewhere not midnight.

Comment: I dont argue that it also displaying date in right format but now In my example format is totally strange (I set this date to person which I store in db and then I read this person from db with date and println date)

Answer (score 0):

**Date to String Conversion**

As per your question you want to convert the date to String

person.getDateOfBirth() is a object get from for code

I  am not familiar the at the return  value of your code snippet person.getDateOfBirth()
but if its java.util.date or java.sql.date 
for both you may use

```
String dob=String.valueOf(person.getDateOfBirth());
```

instead of to toString() Method.
please retrieve a date from db as

```
java.sql.date dob= rs.getDate();
or
java.util.date dob= rs.getDate();
```

based on the format you want